# scrollTo() doesn’t work on iOS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm tying to scroll to my category list but on iOS the command does't work. On Android it's ok..

Code example:

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

scrollTo() {
    this.content.scrollTo(0, 100, 200);
}
```

-

```
<button ion-button (click)="scrollTo()">Down 100px</button>
```

On iOS it goes down 100px but return to top.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: so when you called `scrollTop` it scroll down and then reset to previous position?

Comment: Exactly. I tried to use jQuery but doesn't work too..

Comment: Any error in trace after click ? What if you try this http://jsfiddle.net/WB5qw/

Comment: Can you set the focus on the category list? It should bring it into view, if that is your goal.

Comment: What version of Ionic do you use?

Comment: I can fix based on @JasonKrs answer

Comment: I'm glad I could help. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code that'll help you

http://jsfiddle.net/WB5qw/

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#wrap2").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});

$("#clickme2").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#wrap").offset().top
    }, 2000);
     return false;
});
```

And below the related html

```
<div id="wrap">
    <a href="" id="clickme">Click Me</a>
</div>

<div id="wrap2">
    <a href="" id="clickme2">Go to top</a>
</div>
```

**You should adapt the above JQuery to your situation. Remember at the end of the day, it's all about JAVASCRIPT**

Comment: @sebaferreras Hmm JQuery and Angular...aren't they based on javascript ?  I think that's why OP was able to solve his issue based on the above code. As far as I concerned the problem is solved

Comment: I used part of the code. To be honest, I forgot to try with jQuery animate and I tried with other ways and plugins. This answers reminded me this feature :) Thanks